# Filling the empty part of an array, the functional way in Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I have a function `fill` defined here:

```
/*
  Takes an Array `array` containing null values, and return a copy of that array, filled with the values in `nArray`:

  Usage:
    fill(
      [1, 2, 3],
      [null, 4, null, 5, null]
    )
    // => [1, 4, 2, 5, 3];
*/
const fill = (nArray, array) => {
  let i = 0;
  return array.map((e) => !e ? nArray[i++] : e);
}
```

The counter `i` is defined with `let` and is not immutable, so this code is not purely functional. How would you design this function so it becomes purely functional ?

Comment: That counter is not visible to the outside world, so nobody cares about it. Your code is as readable, functional, and efficient as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make use of [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) :

```
const fill = (nArray, array) => {
  return array.map((e) => !e ? nArray.shift() : e);
}
```

**EDIT :**

Note also, that you will have to check that nArray is not empty, for example :

```
(!e && nArray.length > 0) ? nArray.shift() : e
```

Comment: Well that's even worse, now you're mutating the input to the function. Don't do that. One cannot call that "functional" at all, and "purely" even less.

Comment: @Bergi well, you're right... But I can not delete my answer since it has been accepted! `shift` hides again more the mutation :-)

Comment: You can do `nArray  = nArray.slice()` or `nArray = [...nArray]` to avoid the mutation

Comment: @just-boris yes but in a complicated way as Bergi as proposed, but not as short as my solution if we want to avoid varying index!

Comment: What's wrong with it? `function fill(nArray, array) { nArray = Array.isArray(nArray) ? nArray.slice() : []; return array.map((e) => !e ? nArray.shift() : e);}`. Sorry for bad indents, but I can't format it in the comments

Answer (score -1):

Unless you expect `map` to be some weird function (not the typical `Array.prototype` one) where that impure callback would cause havoc, your code is totally fine. `i` is not observable from the outside world, which makes your function pure.

If you want to avoid all mutation at any cost, you should basically go for a recursive approach:

```
const fill = (nArray, array) =>
  array.length
  ? array[0] 
    ? [array[0]].concat(fill(nArray, array.slice(1)))
    : [nArray[0]].concat(fill(nArray.slice(1), array.slice(1)))
  : []
```

(which is horribly inefficient of course, given JavaScript's lack of cons lists)

You can also use a more declarative implementation of the same thing:

```
const fill = (nArray, array) => {
  if (!array.length) return [];
  const [a, ...as] = array;
  if (a) return [a, ...fill(nArray, as)];
  const [b, ...bs] = nArray;
  return [b, ...fill(bs, as)];
};
```